# Get iPhone location in iOS without preference Location Services set to ON

Tags: ios, geolocation, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, location-services

I'm writing a daemon similar to [Chris Alvares daemon](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/). I want to get the divice location in background without users permission. If the `Location Services` preference in Settings is set to `ON` then I have no problem getting location. For this I'm adding to my executable entitlements `com.apple.locationd.preauthorized` key with boolean value set to true. The problem is when the `Location Services` is off. In this case when I want to get the device location a UIAlertView pops up telling the user that location services is off. There are basically 2 ways but i don't know if they are doable. First, to programmatically turn on/off the Location Services preferences in settings. Second, get location using another code without needing Locations Services to be set `ON`

---

**Update 01:**

I did as iMokhles said and I guess it should work but nothing happens. I guess it is because of the entitlements and I saw the syslog and here is what is logged:

```
iPhone locationd[44] <Error>: Entitlement com.apple.locationd.authorizeapplications required to use _CLDaemonSetLocationServicesEnabled
iPhone myDaemon[3443] <Error>: CoreLocation: CLInternalSetLocationServicesEnabled failed
```

So I added this key to entitlements but it still gave me this error. After I checked Preferences app entitlement I added these lines to the entitlements plist but again nothing happens.

```
<key>com.apple.locationd.authorizeapplications</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.locationd.defaults_access</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.locationd.effective_bundle</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.locationd.status</key>
<true/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Example from FlipSwitch [Location Switch](https://github.com/a3tweaks/Flipswitch/blob/master/Switches/Location)

declare it in your header

```
@interface CLLocationManager
+ (id)sharedManager;
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled;
+ (void)setLocationServicesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
@end
```

Then you can access it using the following code
to check if enabled

```
if([[[objc_getClass("CLLocationManager") sharedManager] locationServicesEnabled] {
    // Enabled
} else {
   // Disabled
}
```

and to enable/disable location

```
[objc_getClass("CLLocationManager") setLocationServicesEnabled:YES];
[objc_getClass("CLLocationManager") setLocationServicesEnabled:NO];
```

and don't forget to import CoreLocation Framework ;)
and

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

**EDIT**
Check code above

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks. `setLocationServicesEnabled` works fine but I can't get the current value from `locationServicesEnabled`. It always returns true value. I have a question. `locationServicesEnabled` is a class method so why did you use `sharedManager` for calling it?

Comment: BTW why does using `[objc_getClass("CLLocationManager") setLocationServicesEnabled:]` instead of `[CLLocationManager setLocationServicesEnabled:]` work? (I mean the log said my problem was with the entitlements while using `objc_getClass` I don't need the entitlements at all!). I have a guess though. I think it's because when you get the class from it's name it is executed from the binary of `CLLocation` framework loaded from `dyld_shared_chache` and because that binary has the right permissions the entitlement is not needed. Am I right?

Comment: `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` works! I don't know why it didn't work a few minutes ago. Maybe my test was wrong:) I have edited your answer a little bit.