# How to turn on/off location services with objective-c on IOS8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, gps, ios8, location-services

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <NotificationCenter/NotificationCenter.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface CLLocationManager

+ (id)sharedManager;
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled;
+ (void)setLocationServicesEnabled:(BOOL)enabled;
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;

@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    id CLLocationManager1 = objc_getClass("CLLocationManager");
    self.mySwitch.on = [CLLocationManager1 locationServicesEnabled];//this works fine
}

- (IBAction)doSomeThing:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    id CLLocationManager1 = objc_getClass("CLLocationManager");
    [CLLocationManager1 setLocationServicesEnabled:sender.selected];//this does't work.
    [CLLocationManager1 locationServicesEnabled:sender.selected];
}
```

1.[Get iPhone location in iOS without preference Location Services set to ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608339/get-iphone-location-in-ios-without-preference-location-services-set-to-on)

2.[IOS8 CLLocationManager.h](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CLLocationManager.h)

I want turn on(off) my iphone6 location services in my app.but this code does't work on IOS8. I don't
know why.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn location services on from your app if the user has switched them off. You can only check with

```
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]
```

whether the user has switched them off or not.

`CLLocationManager` does not have the interface that you show. For the real interface see the [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled). You can check that same reference to see how to use the various types of location services.

Comment: You might want to add that you can start and stop the location manager from getting updates. This will save battery if that's what the op is asking for.

Comment: It's a private API.It works on simulator.I develop it for myself.